# PostgreSQL: Filter out row if value in column is already present

Tags: sql, postgresql

The problem is a little bit difficult to explain in the heading:

I have the following table:

```
ColA | ColB | ColC
-----|------|------
1    |1     |2
1    |1     |3
1    |2     |null
1    |2     |5
1    |2     |6
1    |3     |null
```

I need the following result table:

```
ColA | ColB | ColC
-----|------|------
1    |1     |2
1    |1     |3
1    |2     |5   
1    |2     |6
1    |3     |null
```

Here are the rules:

1. The pair (ColB, ColC) should be unique.
2. If a pair (ColB, ColC) exists with ColC != null, then any other pair (ColB, ColC) with ColC = null should be filtered out.
3. If no pair (ColB, ColC) exists with ColC != null, but a pair (ColB, ColC) with ColC = null exists, then a single pair (ColB, ColC) with ColC = null should appear in the table.

In the example table, the third row is filtered out because of the fourth row. The fifth row is not filtered out because there is no other row with ColB = 3 and ColC != null.

Comment: What happens if there are two or more `NULL` values.  Do you retain all `NULL`s, or only one of them?

Comment: Do you mean for the pair (1,3,null)? Only one pair (1, X, null) should be present if no other X are in the table.

The rule would be: Accept only `null` in ColC if there is no other row with the same values for ColA and ColB having a ColC value != null.

Comment: Your explanation and sample data/results do not make sense.  First, you have no duplicate values for the two columns.  Second you are still filtering out a row.

Comment: Hm? But @TimBiegeleisen already answered my question and...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using analytic functions:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(ColC) OVER (PARTITION BY ColA, ColB) cnt
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC
FROM cte
WHERE (cnt > 0 AND ColC IS NOT NULL) OR cnt = 0;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

The aliased quantity `cnt` is the count of *non* `NULL` `ColC` values across each A-B group.  The `WHERE` clause says to retain all records which are strictly not `NULL`, should `ColC` have at least one non `NULL` value, *or* to retain all records, in the event only `NULL` appears in `ColC`.

Comment: I'v updated my example. Using `MAX` the fourth row would be filtered out, but only the third row should be missing in the result table.

Comment: @matthjes Please consider my updated answer, which is working at least for your latest test data.

Comment: This looks good, thank you very much! Just tested it on my real data.